# How to build the right data structure in order to do a SOAP call?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need to do SOAP call to a webservice, but it seems that I cannot get the data structure right. I've tried everything, but nothing seems to be correct.

**I need to rebuild the following structure in PHP:**

```xml
<StartWorkflowAndGetResultRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID_Workflowdefinition xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/">4003</ID_Workflowdefinition>
    <WorkflowParameterValues xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/">
        <WorkflowParameterValue>
            <ParameterName>ID_Subjekt</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>'.$_SESSION["login-user"].'</ParameterValue>
        </WorkflowParameterValue>
    </WorkflowParameterValues>
    <EntityId xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/" />
    <EntityId2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/" />
    <KommunikationTemplates xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/">
        <KommunikationTemplate Identification="3ecc6ab0-f5f7-41d5-b4a6-eea9c7f019f2">
            <Nummer xmlns="Kommunikation_PQ">+41 71 888 88 88</Nummer>
            <ID_Kommunikation xmlns="Kommunikation_PQ">4068</ID_Kommunikation>
        </KommunikationTemplate>
    </KommunikationTemplates>
    <ResultFieldNames xmlns="http://innosolv.ch/webservices/">
        <string>Success</string>
        <string>ErrorMessage</string>
    </ResultFieldNames>
</StartWorkflowAndGetResultRequest>
```

**My attempt:**

```php
$params = array(
    "ID_Workflowdefinition" => 4003,
    "WorkflowParameterValues" => array(
        array(
            "ParameterName" => "ID_Subjekt",
            "ParameterValue" => $_SESSION["login-user"]
        )
    ),
    "EntityId" => null,
    "EntityId2" => null,
    "KommunikationTemplates" => array(
        array(
            "Nummer" => $phone,
            "ID_Kommunikation" => 4068
        )
    ),
    "ResultFieldNames" => array(
        "Success",
        "Failure"
        )
    );
```

**This is the error response I get from the webservice:**

```html
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to create request using SoapClient, one of the them is to use classmap option. In the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) is not documented but you can find some example in the comments.

If you have a WSDL for your service, there is the [wsdlToPhp](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) library that generates all the classes, entities and examples you need from the web service wsld.